# Why message is not deleted in queue if there is a error after receiving a message in Rabbitmq

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am working on Rabbitmq. I am a newbie in this topic. I have a successful sender and receiver. I have no problem at that but I noticed that if there is a fail in code message stuck in a queue.

If I explain in detail, When I get the message from a queue, the message should be deleted. It should do not matter is there a fail or not. Because queue cant tells this message successfully processed or not. The queue just delivers right? So how the hell queue understands the program that there is a fail in code and keep the message. :D
So I just receive the message again and again.

If u guys help me about the basics of Rabbitmq. I will be glad. Thx Have a good day all of u :D

Comment: Your code must be having some rollback or backout strategy implemented which you are not aware of. If this holds true then , due to processing failure of the messages or events it might get rolled back. Please try to give a snapshot of the code that your are using, failure condition exception handling etc.

Comment: Are you really not interesting in the message entirely anymore after the fault happens? This is not usually the case when using a queue, you tend to want to use a queue to ensure delivery at some point. Maybe you are not looking for throwing away the message but rather moving it to a dead letter queue (DLQ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages stay in queues until they are acknowledged, if a connection that was sent a message fails before the message is acknowledged, the message is not deleted and it's redelivered later.

In your case you may want to activate [automatic acknowledgement](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-modes)